# Peak function decision

Tags: spectroscopy, hydrogen

I am doing a lab of locating hydrogen's spectral lines and peak function fitting is required. It is suggested to use Lorentzian to locate the peaks. I wonder why don't we use Gaussian instead?

Comment: Related : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366104/lorentz-distribution-in-emission-peaks . Also relevant : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94428/lorentzian-vs-gaussian-fitting-functions

Answer (score 0):

- If we consider the transition as an harmonic oscillator, which is driven by an external force, we obtain the  Lorentzian line shape. Hence, the Lorentzian is the correct formula, not the Gaussian.
- These two line shapes (Gaussian and Lorentzian) differ significantly in their  "wings".

Comment: Thanks. I think it is Lorentz oscillator model. However, I do not understand why could we picture the transition of electron as harmonic oscillator. In my view, transition of electron is just the electron dropping from higher energy state to lower state. Why would the dipole (nucleus and electron in the model) oscillating?

Comment: Suppose we apply an el.-mag. fields and the wavelength of this fields is approx. equal to the transition wavelength. What do you expect?

Comment: We would expect a peak at that frequency. By the way, I think I do understand how the oscillator model gives Lorentzian now. Thanks!